# Давайте уберём радиокнопку на проголосованной форме закрытия вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение, дизайн, закрытие-вопросов

Имеется такая форма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я бы предложил убрать радиокнопки, если человек проголосовал. Если мне не изменяет память (в моем возрасте возможно всякое), то раньше, до обновления дизайна, кнопки убирались, если человек голосовал уже за закрытие этого вопроса.

Comment: вроде нет, просто делались неактивными, но уже не уверен :)

Comment: @Grundy, в прошлой версии дизайна их насколько я помню убирали)) а тут они неактивны)) но может это только мне не нравится :)

Comment: не только ... ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Зачем их убирать? о_О

Наоборот надо выбранный вариант отмеченным сделать.

Comment: ну или так)) просто не очень понятно проголосовал человек или нет :)

Comment: Более того - пункт "Специфичная для сообщества причина" следует сделать кликабельным. Иначе хоть отметь его, хоть не отметь - всё одно фигня получится. Просто пару раз натыкался... проголосовав за закрытие по не-русскости текста, копипастю дефиницию пункта в комментарий. А вот ежели забыл - то после отдачи голоса до этого текста уже не добраться, приходится в другой теме открывать меню закрытия и копипастить оттуда - неудобственно.